# mathematics books for studying Econometrics PhD

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-statistics, phd

I started my PhD study in Econometrics last month. Currently I am studying some compulsory course works (Probability theory and Statistical Inference), and also reviewing the literature in my field. I would also like to study some more mathematics, which I believe will make me more prepared for my formal research. Can anyone suggest some math (text)books ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would help if you describe your current mathematics standing. Three semesters of calculus? BSc in math? Any measure theory? Any matrix algebra? Any real analysis? Any programming experience?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the math section at http://econphd.econwiki.com/books.htm. I would also add the two measure theory books from the econometrics section.

Answer (score 0):

You may also check http://tinyurl.com/82eyplb  and if you are willing to spend more http://www.springer.com/economics/econometrics/book/978-0-387-77316-2 will give you some programming experience in R (good for Statistics)